# Set 00:00 as the last timestamp in Excel

Tags: excel, date, datetime

I have a feed of 30 minutes meter readings from MySQL to Excel sorted by the first column which is a datetime format, i.e 10-06-2015 00:00:00, 10-06-2015 00:30:00, 10-06-2015 01:00:00 etc.

Because the reading from 00:00:00 each day is actually data from the last 30 minutes of the day, I need the 00:00:00 reading to be the last row for the day rather than the first (as Excel is sorting by time order 00:00 is the default start of each day). Does anyone know how to format this in Excel so that the 10-06-2015 00:00:00 will come **after** the 10-06-2015 11:30:00 row and not after the 09-06-2015 11:30:00 row?

Comment: Add `1` to all cells with zero times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you are going to find a way to do that using just formats. Reason being that the format doesn't change the underlying value, which is what excel uses to do the sort in the first place.

I would suggest using a helper column in which you use a formula... maybe something like this:

```
=IF(A2-ROUNDDOWN(A2,0)=0,A2+0.99999,A2)
```

Where the first value of your time series is in A1... then copy the formula down and sort on the column B. This worked for me.